# Firebase Messaging not working with iOS 15 in production mode

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have iOS app which supports application above iOS 10. I have followed the tutorial mentioned here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
To integrate firebase into iOS. I have also uploaded the Auth key into Firebase Console.

Now When I tried to fire the push notification from Firebase Console I am able to get the push notification. But when I created the Ad hoc distribution .ipa file I am not able to receive the notification. As you can see while creating Ad hoc build my APNS is set to production.

[image]

Not able to figure out what is the issue. Please help

I am using firebase version 8.8.0